# can't seem to get the correct coordinates to display in the right way

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I'm trying to get the map to paint the set scaleX left side by 180 to 360 longitude and the right side 0 to 180 but I'm abit unsure on a way to make convert these coordinates around as I can't add extra parameters to filRect as I'm only allowed 4 parameters. If I set ScaleX to 0, 360 I get the map the wrong way round. I have 2 classes Plot and Plotmap

My plot class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Plot extends JComponent {
    int width = 1200, height = 1200;
    double xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = 0, ymax = 1, lmin = 0, lmax = 180;

        public int scaleX(double x){
            return (int) (width * (x - xmin) / (xmax + xmin));
        }
        public int scaleY ( double y){
            return (int) (height * (ymin - y) / (ymax - ymin) + height);
        }

        public void setScaleX ( double min, double max){
            xmin = min;
            xmax = max;
        }
        public void setScaleY ( double min, double max){
            ymin = min;
            ymax = max;
        }

    }
```

My plot map class

```
public class Plotmap extends Plot {
    Earth e;
    int point = 20;
    public Plotmap(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        e = new Earth();
        e.readDataArray(filename);

        setScaleX(0, 360);
        setScaleY(-90, 90);
        //setScaleXR(180, 360);
        //setScaleYR(-90, 90);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        this.width = getWidth();
        this.height = getHeight();
        for (int i = 0; i < e.array.length; i++) {
            double longitude = e.array[i][0];
                double latitude = e.array[i][1];
                double alti = e.array[i][2];

                if (alti < 0) 
                    g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 90, 139));
                else
                    g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 139));
                 g.fillRect(scaleX(longitude), scaleY(latitude), point, point);


}
}
}
```

Comment: What would the extra parameters to fill rect achieve? A rectangle is defined by 4 points.

Comment: Do you have a sign error here? `width*(x - xmin) / (xmax + xmin)` you probably want that equal to width if x = xmax;

Comment: Hi @matt, I put the extra parameters in because I thought I could draw the rectangle in 2 parts but I can't do this as you said a rectangle is defined by 4 points. the issue is the longitude points 180 to 360 are on the right side when I need them on the left. same for the longitude points between 0 to 180 they need to be on the right side, Do you have any solutions in which I can switch the points around.

Comment: Can you make your example self contained and compilable? Maybe just populate a double[][] with some systematic information. If I had to guess what you're asking I would say it has to do with constraining your value between the min and max *and* wrapping the values around that  exceed this range?

Comment: One thing I have done in the pass, when your object crosses the boundary, you have to draw it twice. Or for a rectangle draw two rectangles.

Comment: ok I'll give that a go

Comment: Should I just duplicate most of what I've got and plot to suit

Comment: Just something we can use to reproduce your problem, and provide a solution.